# How to change root password for mysql and phpmyadmin

Tags: password, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've set up mysql and phpmyadmin and chose not to set a password when installing hoping that once set up i could login with root and no password but i get the following error from phpmyadmin:

```
Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)
```

I have previously moved the phpmyadmin folder to `/var/www/`

I have tried changing the following line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

but still had no success, so i am wondering is there a way i can change the root passwords for both so i can access phpmyadmin and create databases.

Comment: "the phpmyadmin folder" could be anything. pls state your op:  mv source target , so we understand.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can change the mysql root password by logging in to the database directly (`mysql -h your_host -u root`)  then run

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('yourpassword');
```

phpmyadmin should use that password so not quite sure what you mean by "for both".

Make sure to set the new password into phpmyadmin's `config.inc.php` too, at line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourpassword';
```

Otherwise, phpmyadmin **may not** work, echoing

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Thank you, i was unsure if i had to set a password for both as i have only used WAMP in the past.

Comment: Where can I find config.inc.php?

Comment: Ok, I found it, but there is no line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourpassword';

Comment: usually the config.inc.php is in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Answer (score 30):

It depends on your configuration.
Follow the instruction below to reconfigure phpmyadmin, and reset MySQL password.

1. Ctrl + Alt + T to launch terminal
2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`
3. Connection method for MySQL database for phpmyadmin: unix socket
4. Name of the database's administrative user: `root`
5. Password of the database's administrative user: mysqlsamplepassword
6. MySQL username for phpmyadmin: root
7. MySQL database name for phpmyadmin: phpmyadmin
8. Web server to reconfigure automatically: apache2
9. ERROR 1045
10. ignore
11. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`
12. New password for the MySQL "root" user: mysqlsamplepassword
13. Repeat password for the MySQL "root" user: mysqlsamplepassword
14. After all this run following command on terminal to secure your mysql server.
    sudo mysql_secure_installation
15. Enter current password for root (enter for none): mysqlsamplepassword
16. Change the root password? [Y/n] n
17. Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y
18. Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] y
19. Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] y
20. Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] y

Wish it helps!

Have a nice day!

Comment: MySQL password can be changed using `sudo mysql_secure_installation` as well.

Comment: your wish has not come true here. The op failed. Even

`dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server --force -p low`

was of zero use.

Answer (score 13):

I recently came across this very same issue Ubuntu 12.04. I just couldn't seem to login with root & no password. I set the AllowNoPassword setting to TRUE in the config. Later I found out that I was editing the wrong config.inc.php file to add the AllowNoPassword setting.

```
Edit:
/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
Not:
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

I believe the first is the debian local config file, which will override the usr version.

Comment: /etc/ does carry config while  /usr/  does not.

But the makers of e.g. postfixadmin ignore this valuable convention, creating confusion.