# I have installed mysql on ubuntu 13.10, but don't seem to have rights to do anything?

Tags: 13.10, mysql

This is possibly a problem that affects lots of users, I have have found similar posts, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I have installed mysql on my ubuntu 13.10, however I do not seem to have any rights to do anything. I cannot connect via root, though I do know the root password. I can connect through my user name, though in doing this I get no access rights to create, delete, nor do anything else that is useful.

For example:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE sphider;

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'sphider'
```

or if I try to log in using root:

```
root@rozlockwood-Z87M-D3H:/home/rozlockwood# mysql -u root -p

Enter password:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any help please.

Comment: Read my answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300798/phpmyadmin-login-problem/300841#300841). `root` is different from `root@localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be a matter of:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Follow the prompts to enter a root password during installation.

Then connect:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter the password set during installation.

Comment: thing is, I have already set the mysql-server root password, it was on a blue screen, I know what it is, just mysql doesn't allow me to log in; this is the error message  rozlockwood@rozlockwood-Z87M-D3H:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I am not using the ubuntu root password; I even reconfigured mysql server, to be sure i had the right password, and still it does not allow root access.

Comment: thanks for you help,   i have just got there with an autoremove and a reinstall, i should have tried this first.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this question was dead and didn't log on!
But I'm glad you resolved your problem.